# How are the GNU C preprocessor predefined macros used?

Tags: c, gcc, macros, cygwin

I am trying to figure out how the integer type definitions from various header files are related to each other.

I just installed the CygWin. I opened the `Cygwin\x86\usr\include\machine\_default_types.h`. In it I noticed below code snippets:

```
#ifdef __INT8_TYPE__
typedef __INT8_TYPE__ __int8_t;
```

According to [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html), the `__INT8_TYPE__` is one of the predefined pre-processor macros. And:

> You should not use these macros directly; instead, include the
>   appropriate headers and use the typedefs. Some of these macros may not
>   be defined on particular systems if GCC does not provide a stdint.h
>   header on those systems.

So it seems the `__INT8_TYPE__` should be defined somewhere else. But I searched the whole CygWin installation, there's no definition for it. All I found are some conditional statements just like above one.

Since I shouldn't use it directly. And no other files are defining it. How could this macro ever come into action? Or did I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a predefined macro.  To see them you can:

```
gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null
```

e.g.:

```
$ gcc -dM -E  - < /dev/null | grep __INT
#define __INTMAX_C(c) c ## L
#define __INT8_C(c) c
#define __INT64_C(c) c ## L
#define __INT32_MAX__ 0x7fffffff
#define __INT_FAST32_MAX__ 0x7fffffffffffffffL
#define __INT_FAST16_TYPE__ long int
#define __INT_LEAST32_MAX__ 0x7fffffff
#define __INT_FAST64_TYPE__ long int
#define __INT32_C(c) c
#define __INT_FAST32_TYPE__ long int
#define __INT16_MAX__ 0x7fff
#define __INT8_TYPE__ signed char
#define __INT_LEAST16_TYPE__ short int
#define __INT_FAST16_MAX__ 0x7fffffffffffffffL
#define __INT_LEAST16_MAX__ 0x7fff
#define __INT64_MAX__ 0x7fffffffffffffffL
#define __INT_LEAST64_TYPE__ long int
#define __INT16_TYPE__ short int
#define __INT_LEAST8_TYPE__ signed char
#define __INT_FAST8_MAX__ 0x7f
#define __INTPTR_MAX__ 0x7fffffffffffffffL
#define __INTPTR_TYPE__ long int
#define __INT_FAST64_MAX__ 0x7fffffffffffffffL
#define __INT_MAX__ 0x7fffffff
#define __INT64_TYPE__ long int
#define __INT_LEAST64_MAX__ 0x7fffffffffffffffL
#define __INT_LEAST8_MAX__ 0x7f
#define __INT_LEAST32_TYPE__ int
#define __INT_FAST8_TYPE__ signed char
#define __INTMAX_MAX__ 0x7fffffffffffffffL
#define __INT8_MAX__ 0x7f
#define __INT32_TYPE__ int
#define __INTMAX_TYPE__ long int
#define __INT16_C(c) c
```

Comment: so... it is built into the compiler for a specific platform and I cannot change it?

Comment: @smwikipedia They are definitely platform and compiler specific.  It's likely they are non-modifiable.

Comment: What I really should have said about "non-modifiable" is that these macros are [reserved identifiers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/identifier#Reserved_identifiers) and shouldn't be declared by a program (UB).  You _may_ be able to get away with it, but when you link to another library (e.g. `libc`) your redefined `int8_t` isn't going to match `libc`s `int8_t` in size and/or signedness (unless it's a trivial redefinition -- but what's the point of that?) and so all sort of fun breakage can ensue.