# Forcing sign of a bit field (pre-C++14) when using fixed size types

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, bit-fields

Skip to the bolded part for the essential question, the rest is just background.

For reasons I prefer not to get into, I'm writing a code generator that generates C++ structs in a (very) pre-C++14 environment. The generator has to create bit-fields; it also needs the tightest possible control over the behaviour of the generated fields, in as portable a fashion as possible. I need to control both the size of the underlying allocation unit, and how signed values are handled. I won't get into why I'm on such a fool's errand, that so obviously runs afoul of Implementation Defined behaviour, but there's a paycheck involved, and all the right ways to do what needs to be done have been rejected by the people who arrange the paychecks.

So I'm stuck generating things like:

```
int32_t x : 11;
```

because I need to convince the compiler that this field (and other adjacent fields with the same underlying type) live in a 32 bit word. Generating `int` for the underlying type is not an option because int doesn't have a fixed size, and things would go very wrong the day someone releases a compiler in which int is 64 bits wide, or we end up back on one where it's 16.

In pre-C++14, `int x: 11` might or might not be an unsigned field, and you prepend an explicit `signed` or `unsigned` to get what you need. I'm concerned that int32_t and friends will have the same ambiguity (why wouldn't it?) but compilers are gagging on `signed int32_t`.

**Does the C++ standard have any words on whether the intxx_t types impose their signedness on bit fields?** If not, is there any guarantee that something like

```
typedef signed int I32;
...
I32 x : 11;
...
assert(sizeof(I32)==4); //when this breaks, you won't have fun
```

will carry the signed indicator into the bitfield?

Please note that any suggestion that starts with "just generate a function to..." is by fiat off the table. These generated headers will be plugged into code that does things like s->x = 17; and I've had it nicely explained to me that I must not suggest changing it all to `s->set_x(17)` even one more time. Even though I could trivially generate a set_x function to exactly and safely do what I need without any implementation defined behaviour at all. Also, I've very aware of the vagaries of bit fields, and left to right and right to left and inside out and whatever else compilers get up to with them, and several other reasons why this is a fool's errand. And I can't just "try stuff" because this needs to work on compilers I don't have, which is why I'm scrambling after guarantees in the standard.

Note: I can't implement any solution that doesn't allow existing code to simply cast a pointer to a buffer of bytes to a pointer to the generated struct, and then use their pointer to get to fields to read and write. The existing code is all about s->x, and must work with no changes. That rules out any solution involving a constructor in generated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the C++ standard have any words on whether the intxx_t types impose their signedness on bit fields?

No.

---

The standard's synopsis for the fixed-width integers of `<cstdint>`, [[cstdint.syn]](http://eel.is/c++draft/cstdint#syn) (link to modern standard; the relevant parts of the synopsis looks the same in [the C++11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf)) simply specifies, *descriptively* (not by means of the `signed`/`unsigned` keywords), that they shall be of *"signed integer type"* or *"unsigned integer type"*.

E.g. [for gcc](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/6a41d1aadd82b8a47ff9b619f61a4b7d5d28a85e/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/c_global/cstdint#L41), `<cstdint>` expose [the fixed width integers of `<stdint.h>`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/6a41d1aadd82b8a47ff9b619f61a4b7d5d28a85e/gcc/ginclude/stdint-gcc.h#L34), which in turn are typedefs to predefined pre-processor macros (e.g. [`__INT32_TYPE__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html) for `int32_t`), the latter being platform specific.

The standard does not impose any required use of the `signed` or `unsigned` keywords in this synopsis, and thus bit fields of fixed width integer types will, in C++11, suffer the same implementation-defined behavior regarding their signedness as is present when declaring a plain integer bit field. Recall that the relevant part of [class.bit]/3 prior to C++14 was (prior to action due to [CWG 739](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#739)):

> It is implementation-defined whether a plain (neither explicitly signed nor unsigned) `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, or `long long` bit-field is signed or unsigned. ...

Indeed, the following thread

- [How are the GNU C preprocessor predefined macros used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44896370/how-are-the-gnu-c-preprocessor-predefined-macros-used)

shows an example where e.g. `__INT32_TYPE__` on the answerer's particular platform is defined with no explicit presence of the `signed` keyword:

> ```
> $ gcc -dM -E  - < /dev/null | grep __INT
> ...
> #define __INT32_TYPE__ int
> ```

Comment: Exactly what I needed to know. Depressing, and not surprising, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> it also needs the tightest possible control over the behaviour of the generated fields, in as portable a fashion as possible. I need to control both the size of the underlying allocation unit, and how signed values are handled.

These two goals are incompatible.  Bitfields inherently have portability problems.

If the standard defined the behaviors you want, then the "vagaries of bit fields" wouldn't exist, and people wouldn't bother recommending using bitmasks and shifts for portability.

What you possibly could do is to provide a class that exposes the same interface as a `struct` with bitfields but that doesn't actually use bitfields internally.  Then you could make its constructor and destructor read or write those fields portably via masks and shifts.  For example, something like:

```
class BitfieldProxy
{
public:
    BitfieldProxy(uint32_t& u)
    : x((u >> 4) & 0x7FF),
      y(u & 0xF),
      mDest(u)
    {
    }

    ~BitfieldProxy()
    {
        assert((x & 0x7FF) == x);
        assert((y & 0xF) == y);
        dest = (x << 4) | y;
    }

    BitfieldProxy(const BitfieldProxy&) = delete;
    BitfieldProxy& operator=(const BitfieldProxy&) = delete;

    // Only the last 11 bits are valid.
    unsigned int x;

    // Only the last 4 bits are valid.
    unsigned int y;

private:
    uint32_t& mDest;
};
```

Comment: I *think* you're saying that the answer to "Does the C++ standard have any words on whether the intxx_t types impose their signedness on bit fields?" is no. Ok, but can you quote chapter and verse?
I should have mentioned that there's no opportunity to run constructors and none to modify the code that is already happily casting void* to struct* and then doing their s->x = 17 assignments to read and set things. I could do neat tricks if the generated struct didn't have to be a POD that is simply overlaid on a byte buffer with a pointer cast. I *know* it's foolish, but I can't retire yet...

Comment: The approach I mentioned *could* still work with `void*` to `struct*` casts as long as they don't expect `s->x = 17` assignments to write to the destination immediately; you just would need to manage the lifetimes of the `BitfieldProxy` objects elsewhere and supply pointers to those objects to the existing code.

Comment: As for the question about the standard: I don't know offhand.  I just know that bitfields have historically and notoriously been unportable.  Additionally, it's hard to prove a negative (i.e., the reason for non-portability is because the standard does *not* define behavior), particularly when you're asking about behaviors in potentially *all* pre-C++14 standards.